# Reload DIV (or page) when $.post completes

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div that loads up with data and buttons depending on what some variables are in a SQL database.  When we click those buttons, it changes those SQL variables because of paypal api calls or whatever (such as a "de-activate this account" button.

Right now, when I click the buttons, everything works but the page stays the same, so the "deactivate button" still says "deactivate button" instead of saying "account is deactivated" and other examples like that.  When the page is refreshed they change because the SQL database has changed

Right now, I'm using the following code:

```
location.reload();
```

which effectively refreshes the page, but then you have to click a couple times to get back to the div you were working in.  not a huge deal but annoying none the less.

What I'm wanting to know is if there is a way that when someone clicks the button that, for example, deactivates the account, it displays the message "Account successfully deactivated" then it freshes that DIV only, and loads up the new information based on the SQL database changes.

So far I tried this:

```
var url = 'index.php';
$('#div1-wrapper').load(url + ' #div1');
```

Which actually did what I wanted but after the reload, none of my "clicky" divs (such as a + in the top left corner) would work anymore and therefore the div wouldn't expand like its supposed to.  It's like when it reloaded it didn't contain the right names on the divs but when I viewed source it was the original information so the reload either didn't happen or it doesn't update in the source.

I just need to know if there is a way to reload a div as if the page has been refreshed (so that the PHP code is re-run and the variables re-evaluated) but without refreshing the page.

Also I'd like to do it with JQuery since when you click my buttons, its running jquery $.post and in that post after it alert(data) it does the refresh.

My button calls look like this:

```
$("[id^=cancelbtn_]").click(function(){
     var formid = this.id;
     var myRegexp = /^cancelbtn_(\d+)$/;
     var match = myRegexp.exec(formid);
     var which_row = match[1];
     var username = $("#cancelbtn_"+which_row).attr("attr1");
     $.post('post.php', {'administrator':7,'username':username}, function(data) {
         alert(data);
         location.reload();
     });
 });
```

Comment: instead of `location.reload()` use `$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL + ' #thisdiv');`

Comment: `#thisdiv` is the id of that div that you want to refresh.

Comment: This had the same results as what I mentioned earlier that I tried.  The DIV shows back up but its not able to be interacted with.  I will try to write a fiddle that shows what I'm talking about but it will be later or tomorrow when I have time to do that.  It's like this code loads the div, but the elements aren't named right or aren't clickable for some reason.

Comment: it's because the div is loaded by jquery so you need to write `$("[id^=cancelbtn_]").on('click',function(){` and it will work next onwards. also you have to check something like value that if value 1 then change button text and type else something other. i hope you are able to understand .

Comment: If I do this:

$('#main_licensee_edit').load(document.URL + ' #main_licensee_edit');

The #main_licensee_edit DIV permanently hides.  I have another span I click to unhide certain DIVS depending on the section you are working on.  When I use the code you are suggesting, after it reloads, the DIV doesn't show up anymore after clicking the span.  If I change it to this:

$('#mle_wrapper').load(document.URL + ' #main_licensee_edit');

#mle_wrapper is just a DIV surrounding the other DIV.  If I click the SPAN now, the #main_licensee_edit DIV shows back up but its not interactable

Comment: changing the button code to .on('click',function{  had the same results as the .click did.

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle but there is to much going on to just recreate a useable fiddle.

I'll just have to stick with location.reload() for now.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: `.on()` should work since it live binds the event. If it's not working, check the console log to see if some other javascript is breaking the execution chain.